# how to make div click-able?

Tags: javascript, css, html, click

```
<div><span>shanghai</span><span>male</span></div>
```

For div like above,when mouse on,it should become cursor:pointer,and when clicked,fire a

javascript function,how to do that job?

**EDIT**: and how to change the background color of div when mouse is on?

**EDIT AGAIN**:how to make the first span's width=120px?Seems not working in firefox

Comment: why don't you use an a-tag for the link? If you set display:block for the a-tag it behaves like the div. This solution would be more semantically. You still can add the event listener from the answers below on the a-tag.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Give it an ID like "something", then:

```
var something = document.getElementById('something');

something.style.cursor = 'pointer';
something.onclick = function() {
    // do something...
};
```

Changing the background color (as per your updated question):

```
something.onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
something.onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '';
};
```

Comment: Remember to do this inside the window.onload-event.

Comment: Or, place the script somewhere beneath the element being targeted.

Comment: btw,how to make the first span's width:120px?

Comment: span doesn't take a width because it's an inline element (it's as wide as it's content), can you make it a div instead?

Comment: why inline element can't take a width?

Comment: i changed that div to a table,and span to td,this time works.is td an inine element or not?

Comment: Don't use a table unless you're showing tabular data. You can give a span a width, you just need to set it to display:block; first.

Comment: Then you can´t assign a width, it´s that simple.

Comment: but i can assign a width to td,aren't they both inline elements?

Comment: @Wondering,so all TDs in a TR use float to display like inline?

Comment: Regarding the background color it would likely be best to do this in your css stylesheet: `.class:hover{background:#bbb;}`

Answer (score 34):

`<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="theFunction()">`

is the simplest thing that works.

Of course in the final solution you should separate the markup from styling (css) and behavior (javascript) - read on it [on a list apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation) for good practices on not just solving this particular problem but in markup design in general.

Comment: and how to change the background color of div when mouse is on?

Comment: add a hover on the css

Answer (score 11):

The simplest of them all:

```
<div onclick="location.href='where.you.want.to.go'" style="cursor:pointer"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to use jQuery:

```
$('#mydiv')
  .css('cursor', 'pointer')
  .click(
    function(){
     alert('Click event is fired');
    }
  )
  .hover(
    function(){
      $(this).css('background', '#ff00ff');
    },
    function(){
      $(this).css('background', '');
    }
  );
```

Comment: As has been posted in a comment above; why use a framework for such a simple thing?

Comment: If there are many simple things in your project, I think a good framework can save a great deal of time.
If you want a javascript framework, jQuery is a best option :)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use a CSS class called clickbox and activate it with jQuery:

```
$(".clickbox").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
 });
```

Now the only thing you have to do is mark your div as clickable and provide a link:

```
<div id="logo" class="clickbox"><a href="index.php"></a></div>
```

Plus a CSS style to change the mouse cursor:

```
.clickbox {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Easy, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

add the [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) attribute

```
<div onclick="myFunction( event );"><span>shanghai</span><span>male</span></div>
```

To get the cursor to change use [css's cursor rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Cursor).

```
div[onclick] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The selector uses an attribute selector which does not work in some versions of IE. If you want to support those versions, add a class to your div.

Comment: Why's this obtrusive? It does what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

As you updated your question, here's an obtrustive example:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");

    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    div.onmouseover = function()
    {
        div.style.background = "#ff00ff";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="theFunction()" onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" onmouseout="this.style.background=''" ><span>shanghai</span><span>male</span></div>
```

This will change the background color as well

Answer (score 1):

If this div is a function I suggest use cursor:pointer in your style like style="cursor:pointer" and can use onclick function.

like this

```
<div onclick="myfunction()" style="cursor:pointer"></div>
```

but I suggest you use a JS framework like [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) or [extjs](http://www.extjs.com)

Comment: Why should he/she use an entire framework for something so simple!?!?

Comment: cursor:hand is no good on browsers other than IE. cursor:pointer is the cross browser way of doing "the hand"