# Need to toggle CSS slide-in function with click on different div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyw7jyxq/5/) and i need to slide in, when clicking on a div, and not when page is loaded. Simultaneously it should be possible to close by clicking anywhere outside the slide-in box.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $(".slide-in").addClass("active");
        console.log($(".slide-in"));   
    });
});
```

I think the solution could be some kind of toggle system, but i can't figure out how to?

Thank you!

Comment: You are duplicating.

Comment: @PraveenKumar What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opens the slider on click of .button. Closes it on click anywhere outside the slider (including the button)

```
var isOpened = false;
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if(isOpened && e.target.className=='slide-in') {
    $(".slide-in").removeClass("active");
    isOpened = false;
  } else if(!isOpened && e.target.className=='button'){
    $(".slide-in").addClass("active");
    isOpened = true;
  }
});
```

---

Better is to use IDs. So your code would be:

```
<div id="slide-in"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
var isOpened = false;
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in') {
    $("#slide-in").removeClass("active");
    isOpened = false;
  } else if(!isOpened && e.target.id=='button'){
    $("#slide-in").addClass("active");
    isOpened = true;
  }
});
```

You'll also need to change the CSS from classes to IDs

Comment: This is awesome, but at the moment, the #slide-in closes, when you click itself. I only wants it to close, when you click anywhere outside the box?

Comment: Edited my answer. Now it closes only on clicking outside the box.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you help me again? If i would like the button to disappear, whenever the #slide-in is active. Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: Add $("#button").hide() to the opening part and $("#button").show() to the closing part of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById('yourDiv');

someDiv.style.cursor = 'pointer';
someDiv.onclick = function() {
  //do something  
}
```

[how to make div click-able?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057416/how-to-make-div-click-able)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick.

Edit:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".button").on("click",function(){
    if($(".slide-in").hasClass("active")){
      $(".slide-in").removeClass("active");
    }else{
        $(".slide-in").addClass("active");
    }  
  });
});
```

Comment: This closes only if the .slide-in is clicked, not "anywhere outside the slide-in box"

Comment: It sort of works, but when i need to close it, i would like the button to trigger it back. At the moment you need to click the slide-in itself. How can I change this - thank you!

Comment: @MikkelLehrmann Well I edited the answer, Depending on you needs, you can use this as well...

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/jne1rasb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click dblclick', function(e) {

    $('.slide-in').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();

  });
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $(".slide-in").removeClass("active");
  });
});
```