# Allow User to Input Number, and output in respective card? JS, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, currency

I am trying to write an little fun website in which allows a user to input numbers entered on a keyboard, and on the event of a *solve* button press (which I have not included yet in the below code) will attempt to solve, then output, the Sudoku in the boxes of `.card`

What do I implement in my ***.js*** file in order to capture the input then change the respective cards value to a number?

`.card.[number entered]::before { content: [number entered] }` <-- will be used

As well as, inputting the entered numeric-key in to the JavaScript `grid` array, in order to be solved?

How would I then output the solved JS `grid` into its respective `.card.[number entered]::before { content: [number entered] }`?

---

If this is confusing, please let me know and I will try to include more information.

---

***index.html:***

```js
let MAX = 9,
  BLANK = 0,
  SPACE = " ",
  LINE = "|",
  NEW_ROW = "-------------------------------------";

let grid = [
  [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 7, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8],
  [0, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
];

let pair = [0, 0];

function test() {
  console.log(grid);

  if (solve(grid)) {
    console.log(grid);
  } else {
    console.log("No solution exists for the given Sudoku");
  }
}

function used_in_row(grid, row, num) {
  for (let col = 0; col < MAX; col++) {
    if (grid[row][col] === num) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function used_in_col(grid, col, num) {
  for (let row = 0; row < MAX; row++) {
    if (grid[row][col] === num) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function used_in_box(grid, box_start_row, box_start_col, num) {
  for (let row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      if (grid[row + box_start_row][col + box_start_col] === num) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function is_safe(grid, row, col, num) {
  return !used_in_row(grid, row, num) &&
    !used_in_col(grid, col, num) &&
    !used_in_box(grid, row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num);
}

function get_unassigned_location(grid) {
  for (let row = 0; row < MAX; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < MAX; col++) {
      if (grid[row][col] === BLANK) {
        pair[0] = row;
        pair[1] = [col];
        return pair;
      }
    }
  }

  return "GRID_FULL";

}

function solve(grid) {
  if ("GRID_FULL" === get_unassigned_location(grid)) {
    return true;
  }

  pair = get_unassigned_location(grid);
  let row = pair[0];
  let col = pair[1];

  for (let num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
    if (is_safe(grid, row, col, num)) {

      grid[row][col] = num;
      if (solve(grid)) {
        return true;
      }
      grid[row][col] = BLANK;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  background-color: #e64a19;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-auto-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 8rem;
}

.card.1::before {
  content: "1";
}

.card.2::before {
  content: "2";
}

.card.3::before {
  content: "3";
}

.card.4::before {
  content: "4";
}

.card.5::before {
  content: "5";
}

.card.6::before {
  content: "6";
}

.card.7::before {
  content: "7";
}

.card.8::before {
  content: "8";
}

.card.9::before {
  content: "9";
}

.winner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: animate 0.5s linear;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.winner button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card" data-index="1"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="2"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="3"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="4"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="5"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="6"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="7"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="8"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="9"></div>

    <div class="card" data-index="10"></div>

    <div class="card" data-index="11"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="12"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="13"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="14"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="15"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="16"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="17"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="18"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="19"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="20"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="21"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="22"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="23"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="24"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="25"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="26"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="27"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="28"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="29"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="30"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="31"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="32"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="33"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="34"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="35"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="36"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="37"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="38"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="39"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="40"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="41"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="42"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="43"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="44"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="45"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="46"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="47"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="48"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="49"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="50"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="51"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="52"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="53"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="54"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="55"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="56"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="57"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="58"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="59"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="60"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="61"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="62"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="63"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="64"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="65"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="66"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="67"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="68"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="69"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="70"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="71"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="72"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="73"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="74"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="75"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="76"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="77"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="78"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="79"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="80"></div>
    <div class="card" data-index="81"></div>

  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How the [grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcnrf.png) looks like

Comment: You will need a mouse click event. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057416/how-to-make-div-click-able

Also, you might want to consider a more concise way of creating 9x9 grid. Tables? Or at least programatically create them in .js?

Comment: Adding onto @SnowGroomer: consider using a canvas for this!

Comment: @ChloeDev Would it be possible with canvas, to implement one huge square area, then with JavaScript, split up those spaces so that they create a 9x9 grid? And then, using JS *classList* to add a CSS class to them? How would I enter a numeral into a certain box, then upload that numeral into the sudoku.js *grid* array?